# Sawtooth validator is not committing any transactions

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have set up some code from GitHub on the local system. It works smoothly as intended. But when I make changes in client-side code (JS SDK) and try restarting the entire docker process. When setting up role permission as follows:

sawtooth identity policy create --key /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv policy_1 "PERMIT_KEY $(cat /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.pub)" --url http://rest-api:8008

the transaction gets timeout and never gets committed.

Original code link:

https://github.com/mansoorop/Vehicle-management-system-VMS-

Changes:

https://github.com/swapnildeshmukh15/VMS-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with intkey processor compatibility, there are 2 possible solutions for this.

1. Either upgrade intkey TP to match the latest release of the sawtooth core.
2. Downgrade the sawtooth core compatible with mentioned intkey version.